# How do I plot a set of points and connect the points with a line in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, core-plot

I added CorePlot to my project in XCode but I'm not sure how to now use it to plot a function. I have some code that outputs one array with a set of x values and another array with a set of y values. How do I plot these points (connected with a line) on the window (the window that pops up when you build your project)? I tried following an example but it looks like it was for iOS. Also, Youtube is (surprisingly) devoid of CorePlot examples for Mac apps using Swift 3.

**Update:** Gonna try to figure it out while I'm waiting. I'll post updates as I go. For example, I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012291/multiple-scatterplots-using-core-plot-and-swift) on here but it seems to be for an iOS app. Gonna see what I can do to modify it for my Cocoa app.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the example apps included with Core Plot? You'll need a `CPTScatterPlot` to make a line plot.

Comment: @EricSkroch yes, but I mistakenly followed an example for an iOS app. But I guess that still counts as getting the general idea, right?

Comment: There are Mac examples, too. Either way, the basic principles are the same.

Comment: @EricSkroch I found the examples on the Github for CorePlot, but now how do I actually use them to test them out? For example, how about [this one](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/tree/master/examples/CPTTestApp)? Do I just copy all of the files in the `Source` folder and put them into my project? Note - I'm using Swift 3, not sure if this example also works for this language.

Comment: Each example app has its own project. Open the project and run the app. There is a workspace file with links to all of them to make it easier to switch between apps when looking through the examples. The Mac DatePlot app and the iPhone CPTTestApp are both written in Swift. The versions on the `release-2.3` branch are in Swift 3.

Comment: @EricSkroch Ok so I've been reading through a few of the examples. Do you happen to know how I can make only a section of the output window hold a graph? Do I need to use a special kind of view? I want to have settings on the left and the graph on the right. The settings will be used to modify the graph. I see that there is an option called "Vertical Split View Controller", could this be it?

Comment: Yes. Put the settings view on the left and the graph hosting view on the right.